# What is the benefit in CUDA's reinterpreting builtins over C/C++ reinterpretation?

Tags: casting, cuda, built-in

CUDA has some built-in device-side functions for reinterpreting integral as floating-point values and vice versa:

```
float     __int_as_float(int);
int       __float_as_int(float);
double    __longlong_as_double(long long);
long long __double_as_longlong(double);
```

why, if it all, is it preferable to use these over a generic:

```
y = reinterpret_cast<T&>(x);
```

or even the C-language

```
y = *((T*)(&x));
```

?

Comment: Just asking (not really an expert with CUDA) - but do we know that the GPU architectures supported by CUDA necessarily have 'standard' (IEEE) representations for floating-point types?

Comment: @Adrian: Basically yes, but see [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#floating-point-standard) for details.

Comment: Use the built-ins, that is why they are provided. You might imagine that (in an ideal world and on the right architecture), the built-in functions emit code which directly leverages instructions for the conversion. You would be relying on compiler idiom analysis with language based casting. I know what I would trust more

Comment: @talonmies: When you're writing templated code, and need to reinterpret, it's more of a hassle to use these built-ins - I need custom specializations. So, I'm wondering whether there actually is any benefit by now, and what it is. Rephrased the title to clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: Have you built any comparison test cases and studied the generated SASS code?